# create a java array of double (primitive) in matlab

Tags: java, arrays, matlab

I would like to be able to declare a java array of `double` in matlab. In java you would do something like this:

`double[] arr = new double[4];`

Now I want to do the same thing in Matlab. I have tried the following:

```
arr = javaArray('D', 100);
arr = javaArray('[D', 100);
```

It gives me the `No class [D can be located on the java class path` error.

I know I can create an array of `Double` with `arr = javaArray('com.lang.Double', 100);`, but this is not a primitive type and would require further conversion.

Comment: Do you really need this function? Use a matlab double vector/matrix, it can be passed to any java function which requires a java array.

Comment: I'm receiving a java list and want to use the `toArray(newArr)` function to turn it into a double vector. The current conversion method converts it to a cell and and then to a double.

Comment: Basically, the question is how to use the `public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` to output a java `double []` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#toArray(T[]). I would write a java class which does it, maybe someone has a better solution.

Comment: That is another way of posing the question. I need to be able to do this in Matlab though. I guess I could always write the java and compile into a .jar and load that into matlab :/